# Facebook "Tabs"

Tags: facebook, web-applications

This might be the wrong place, but when I am making a static HTML page for facebook, it gives me the option to add a second "tab" - what is that exactly? Is that one of the icons on the left like "Photos" and "Videos"? What if I want to add another section like "Photos" and "Videos" are those apps? Can I make those and add them to the left? So many questions but facebook development is quite a confusing thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that one of the icons on the left like "Photos" and "Videos"?

Yes

> What if I want to add another section like "Photos" and "Videos" are those apps?

Yes

> Can I make those and add them to the left?

Yes

You may want to ask a more specific question about the process you're going through to get some more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook changed things a bit ago. At one point they had a more "tabbed" look on pages across the top of each page and they had a Static FBML app in EditPage/App. Now they moved those tabbed links to a list under the photo to the left and removed the StaticFBML app button. You are able to change these links, add your own custom FBML etc.

Use this to add the app to your page.
https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=fdfd01c9df7d644a68a4e989ae861e44&pages=1&page=191733884195510

Edit the Settings and add your HTML or FBML.